# android display orientation

Tags: android

I used the following piece of code in onCreate() method... But still it is displaying both messages while transists from landscape to protrait. Please help me to getrid of it..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     WindowManager wm=getWindowManager();
    Display dis=wm.getDefaultDisplay();

   if(dis.getWidth()>dis.getHeight())
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Portarit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Comment: are you getting two message in single orientation?

Comment: yes...I am getting two messages in single orientation.

Answer (score 2):

use `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` instead; width and height of the screen are fixed when you ask the defaultDisplay(). Otherwise you could do with `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels` and `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels`.